# How to transfer ether from Metamask to Myetherwallet

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, metamask

I have some Eth on Metamask. How Can i safely transfer it to myetherwallet?

I have created a 'wallet' on myetherwallet, And I can clearly see an 'account address' on the right. Is this where I send it to?

Is it that simple ? Or do i need to export the private key of my metamask wallet on myetherwallet.com first? Then make the transfer on myetherwallet.com itself

I'm guessing yes? 
Because i thought there was gas and fees, but metamask doesn't ask me about that when i click the 'SEND' button. The only box it has for anything else is - Transaction data.

Or can i send directly from Metamask browser wallet address -> Myetherwallet address

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It is that simple! You do *not* need to import your private key from MetaMask into MyEtherWallet. To send ether to another destination (either yourself or another user's account), all you need is the account address. So, copy your receiving address out of MyEtherWallet, and put that in the "Recipient Address" field in MetaMask.

There are "gas and fees" and stuff, they're just on the next screen in the wizard flow of sending Ether in MetaMask. So, hit "Send", and then you'll see them. On that second screen, hitting "Accept" is the final confirmation that sends the transaction to be mined. You don't need anything in the "transaction data" field because you're not activating a smart contract, you're just sending Ether value. Set your gas price to 2 GWei (unless you're really wanting it to confirm really quickly), and you should be set to go!

Answer (score 1):

#### You can reuse the same address if both connected to same network.

1. Make sure you are connected to same network on both Metamask and MEW.
2. If you are connected to the same network you can simply reuse your Meatmask wallet on MEW by importing it.
3. Or you can create new wallet in MEW itself and transfer Metamask to MEW address.